# docker or k8s args causing: executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Tags: docker

I have the following go code, for passing args/flags

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

var (
    textFlag = flag.String("text", "", "text to put on the webpage")
)

func main() {
    flag.Parse()
    http.HandleFunc("/", HelloServer)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}

func HelloServer(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s!", *textFlag)
}
```

deploy:

```
kind: Pod
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: bar-app
  labels:
    app: bar
spec:
  containers:
    - name: bar-app
      image: localhost:5001/hello-app:1.0
      imagePullPolicy: Always
      args:
        - "-text=bar"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.19 as builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./src/go/*.go ./
COPY ./src/go/go.mod ./   
RUN go mod download

RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -mod=readonly -v -o server

FROM alpine:3
RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates
COPY --from=builder /app/server /server
CMD ["/server"]
```

But when I deploy it to k8s I get:

```
Error: failed to create containerd task: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: exec: "-text=bar": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown
```

If I remove the arg from the deployment it works:

```
  args:
    - "-text=bar"
```

Comment: What's in your image's Dockerfile?  (Kubernetes `args:` replaces Dockerfile `CMD`; Kubernetes `command:` replaces `ENTRYPOINT`.)

Comment: @david-maze shows the issue. Your Pod config's `args` overrides (replaces) your container's `CMD`. So, instead of running your Go binary with the `-text` flag, all that's being run is the flag (i.e. `-text=""`) which isn't a valid binary and so doesn't work. It is good practice to use `ENTRYPOINT` in your container `ENTRYPOINT ["/server"]` and use `CMD` for any default flags. Also note that `--text` (two hyphens) is preferred for long flags.

Comment: As @DavidMaze and @DazWilkin mention the `command` and `args` of a kubernetes pod will override the `CMD` of a docker image. Refer this [k8's offical document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/#define-a-command-and-arguments-when-you-create-a-pod) on defining the args of a container for a detailed view.